# Move a MovieClip to given destination x & y protectile to arc

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I want a movieclip to move to mouseclick destination x & y from current position in projectile  arc. I want to do it in 8 directions as well.... Please help...

Comment: Draw a tween with a simple parabola as movement function, should do.

Comment: Thanx Vesper... but when i did so, the y position it takes by itself as per parabolic function and is not same as my destination x..

Comment: Well, you want to move your MC from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2). You move by X normally, progressively, linearly, and by Y you need 2 components, one is linear, the other is parabolic, with start and end of parabola being 0, and middle being -H. I'm inept with coding tweens, so I can give only an algorithm on how to build a tween.

Comment: What do you mean by "8 directions"? You mean a projectile trajectory starting in current position and ending at mouse position regardless of direction? Gravity would pull always in the same direction (positive y in AS3) right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need two tweens, one for X and one for Y. Say you've locked "destX" and "destY", also "sourceX" and "sourceY". You want your function that's by Y to always align itself by a certain value, aka elevation. Make a function for tweening Y ilke this:

```
function yParabola(t:Number,b:Number,c:Number,d:Number,p:Number=-30):Number {
    return b+c*t/d+4.0*(t/d*(1.0-t/d)*p);
}
```

And feed it into your tween for Y. The main trouble is that fl.transitions.Tween engine cannot make its tweens to pass 5th or 6th parameter in their easing function, so you might need to use a set of different parabolic functions like this:

```
function bigParabola(t:Number,b:Number,c:Number,d:Number):Number {
    return yParabola(t,b,c,d,-100);
}
```

and feed them into different tweens you might need.

Comment: Sorry for late reply.... Thanks vesper... will look into that and update the comment...

Comment: hey Vesper, Can you tel me what these t,b,c & d fields represent...

Comment: [The manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/easing/Strong.html) says, first parameter `t` is current time offset, `b` is starting value, `c` is total value change, and `d` is total duration. The function result is directly applied to the property.